# Ensure a particular user can only see their own user details - Using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Working with Spring / Spring security on a small project at the moment and having difficulty implementing this feature.  Ideally I only want user1 to view the details of user1 and not those of 2,3 or 4 for example.

I've implemented Spring Security with Roles and understand that I can retrieve a UserDetails object or a principle, I'm not sure exactly but I know I can retrieve the details of the current logged in user using one of, what appears to be many methods.

This is what I'm currently using as a proof of concept when we go to the Admin/home page:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Gamer gamer = gamerService.findGamerByEmail(auth.getName());

    System.out.println("Auth: " + auth.getName());
    System.out.println("Gamer: " + gamer.getName() + gamer.getId() + gamer.getEmail());
```

The security config takes care of whether or not the current user can access because of the roles assigned to it.

I believe I should be able to go to the url of `/mysite/viewUserDetails` and have that page display information of the current user but I cannot find any examples of this, I've found plenty of example that prove a logged in user can view a page but none that specify checks in place to ensure user1 can only view user1's details.

On an older page I do this to display information for a particular user but I understand this to be bad practice-

```
<a th:href="@{/gamer/{gamerid}/games/excited (gamerid=${gamer.id}) }">
```

*Worth noting that this isn't using any form of login/registration to pull out this info, I'm simple using the id I pass in as part of the DB query.

It maps onto :

```
   @RequestMapping("/gamer/{gamerid}/games/excited")
public String getExcited(@PathVariable final Long gamerid, Model model){

    addGamerListAttributes(model, gamerid, "EXC");
    return "games";
}
```

So my question becomes, and I hope you can point in the right direction, How can I implement a solution where a user can only view his/her details and how should this be represented via the form and connecting controllers as passing ids in the url is kinda ugly (I could use a guid but...)

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `@PreAuthorize` annotation. It is possbile to annotate given endpoint with it and create custom logic in a bean. Then you can use custom method to allow or disallow the endpoint to proceed :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @RequestMapping("/gamer/{gamerid}/games/excited")
    @PreAuthorize("@authenticationService.hasAccess(#gamerid)")
    public String getExcited(@PathVariable final Long gamerid, Model model){

        addGamerListAttributes(model, gamerid, "EXC");
        return "games";
    }
}
```

Service class :

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService {
    public boolean hasAccess(String tgamerid) {
        //implement logic here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Method `hasAccess` in the `AuthenticationService` should return boolean. `@PreAuthorize` will be launched before controller handler method is invoked. The controller above is just an example. You can pass `Authentication` object in SPeL expression in `@PreAuthorize` annotation to service method or get it from security context inside service class, to implement logic which fits your needs. More information can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security) and in [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-pre-post-annotations).

Comment: Thanks Michalk, sorry for the delay in replying! I like the idea of what preauthorise can offer, seems very elegant.  I do prefer the option where the inis not passed in though and is instead extracted from the securitycontext.  I presume having the 'hasAccess' in addition to extracting idea from the SC would be somewhat redundant?

Comment: In my solution you would have to get gamerId from SC and compare it to gamerId from pathVariable, and for example check if they are the same or implement any other logic. The option without passing gamerId in path and getting gamer's games based on gamerId from SC is just another option and it depends on you what you will choose.

Comment: ok, but if I remove the gamerId from the path, then I think that negates the need for the check?  if it were /getmygames and then in the controller I extract from SC, would that, with your experience, work ok?  Would I still need the preauth etc

Comment: Yes if you remove gamerId from path, preauthorize in this case will be useless.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite an easy choice. Either you have an entry point like:

```
@RequestMapping("/gamer/{gamerid}/games/excited")
```

and you manually check that the user in session can access the requested resource, or you have something like

```
@RequestMapping("/my-games")
```

that automatically reads the user id from the security context.

More than a security choice, I'd pick one depending on code reuse and future use-cases (for example the same page/set of pages can be seen by more than one user).

Comment: Thanks Raffaele, sorry for the delay in replying, we went away for a few days.  I prefer the second option as don't really want to pass the userId in anywhere, especially in the url.  As for code reuse, I'm at an early stage of development with the future design not being fully mapped out - this is a hobby/learning project more than anything else.  
Using the second, I see how I can display what I need to by extraction, would I be right in thinking that pulling the id from the securitycontext means that another user would not be able to 'inject' the id anywhere and see someone else's data?